# Web Apps behind Azure Application Gateway - what is the IP of outgoing requests

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, gateway, azure-virtual-network

I have multiple web apps on Azure that I want to put behind an Application Gateway in order to use a single domain name with path routing.

However, my web apps needs to connect to a db outside of Azure. So I wonder what will the IP of the requests from these web apps to the db would be? I hope it will be the gateway public IP so I only have to authorize one IP at my db provider but I don't find any docs to confirm it (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wonder what will the IP of the requests from these web apps to
>   the db would be?

If you want your web apps to connect a database outside  Azure, you may need [**App service Environment**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). Because the Web Apps need VNet to connect other resources. Also, due to the date base is outside  Azure , you need to create VPN gateway to connect it. This connection is between the Web App and the database, not Application Gateway and Database.

**So, the IP of requests from those Web Apps is not the IP of Application Gateway, It depends on the VNet in App Service Environment.**

This picture explains how this environment works:

[image]

> I hope it will be the gateway public IP so I only have to authorize
>   one IP at my db provider but I don't find any docs to confirm it (or
>   not).

Also, if you still want to use one IP to connect other resources, you can also add Internal Loadbalancer to achieve that.

[image]

You can see more details about [**Integrating your ILB ASE with an Application Gateway**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/integrate-with-application-gateway) to help your deploy resources.

Please let me know if this answer helps.

Comment: Hi, @François , If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Comment: Tks for the diagrams, they help. But at the end I feel it's way too complicated for me at that stage.

Comment: Hi,@François. Yes,you're right. It may be quiet complicated for new user. To  achieve the requirement,you may need to do lots of work. But luckily, we still can achieve this.;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Azure Web App's Hybrid connection. This provides a TCP tunnel in a secured fashion between your azure web app and your SQL db. There is a service bus in between and you have to install the relay agent in your network that does the outgoing communication to this service bus.

[Hybrid connection diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljXfG.png)

Details are at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

The app gateway's public IP address can't be leveraged nor is it necessary to manage connections between Azure Web Apps and databases outside of Azure. The web apps have their own IP addresses.

On another note, my blog post may be useful to understand how the architecture and configuration between app gateway and azure web app.